# form onclick validation JQUERY

Tags: jquery, onclick, validation

I am trying to validate a simple form before the php process.
When I let every input empty, the form is stopped, but if I stay on the same page and fill every inputs, the form won't submit.

I guess the return false; stays at the first validation. I'm a beginner :)

So here is an excerpt:

**HTML**

```
<input onblur="validName();" type="text"  name="name" id="name">
<textarea id="message" name="message" onblur="validMess();" rows="5"></textarea>

<input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="validSubmit();" value="send">
```

**JQUERY**

```
function validSubmit() {
var message = $("#message").val();
var name = $("#name").val();

    if( name == ''){
        $("#valid-name").removeClass('hide'); // if empty = show error message
        $("#form").submit(function(e){
            return false;
        });
    }
    else {
        $("#valid-name").addClass('hide'); // all good = hide error message
        $("#form").submit(function(e){
            return true;
        });
    }


    if(message == ''){
        $("#valid-mess").removeClass('hide'); // if empty = show error message
        $("#form").submit(function(e){
            return false;
        });
    }
    else { 
        $("#valid-mess").addClass('hide'); // all good = hide error message
        $("#form").submit(function(e){
            return true;
        });
    }

}
```

IDs : valid-name and valid-mess are two error messages set to display: none; by default.

I'm a bit lost, the answer can be in JS or Jquery I don't mind.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't call `submit` from the `submit` callback, just return `false` when it's not OK :

```
function validSubmit() {
    var message = $("#message").val();
    var name = $("#name").val();
    $("#valid-name,#valid-mess").addClass('hide');
    var ok = true;
    if (name == ''){
        $("#valid-name").removeClass('hide');
        ok = false;
    }
    if (message == ''){
        $("#valid-mess").removeClass('hide');
        ok = false;
    }
    return ok;
}
```

Also, as noted by Barmar, this isn't the best way to bind the validation. Instead of binding to the click event, you'd better use

```
$('#id_of_the_form').submit(validSubmit);
```

Comment: You should also call `validSubmit()` in the form's `onsubmit` handler.

Comment: Yep, it works perfectly, thank very much to you two !
I owe you a beer ;)